# Timing my c code

Tags: c, integration, openmp, timing

I have written a code in C for finding the volume between two parabloids. Although the code takes about 7 seconds to run when I check it on my clock, using the inbuilt clock function gives me only 2.6 seconds.

I have run the same code using openmp after parallelizing it and it takes 7 seconds there. Can someone please point out the flaw in my timing?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <time.h>

int main ()
{
    int i, j, k;
    double xmin = 0;
    double xmax = 0.707;
    long Nx = 10000, Ny, n;
    double dx = (xmax - xmin)/(Nx-1);
    double x[Nx];
    double Nelemy[Nx];
    double y, z1, z2;
    double vol1[Nx], vol2[Nx];
    double sum1 = 0, sum2 = 0;
    double start, end, elapsedTime;

    start = clock();

    // Fill in the array containing values at x nodes and number of elements at in y at each node of x
    for (i=0; i<Nx; i++)
    {
        x[i] = 0;
        x[i] = i*dx;
        y = sqrt(1 - 2*x[i]*x[i]);
        n = y/dx;
        Ny = ceil(n) + 1;
        Nelemy[i] = 0;
        Nelemy[i] = Ny;
    }

    // Calculate area for each cell
    double dA = dx*dx;

    // Calculate the value of z for each cell
    for (i=0; i<Nx; i++)
    {
        vol1[i] = 0;
        vol2[i] = 0;
        Ny = Nelemy[i];
        double Y[Ny];
        for (k=0; k<Ny; k++)
        {
            Y[k] = 0;
            Y[k] = k*dx;
        }

        for (j=0; j<Ny; j++)
        {
            z1 = 5 * ( x[i] * x[i] + Y[j] * Y[j]);
            z2 = 6 - 7 *  x[i] * x[i] - Y[j] * Y[j];
            // Calculate the partial volume
            vol1[i] = vol1[i] + dA * z1;
            vol2[i] = vol2[i] + dA * z2;
        }
    }

    // print the contents of vol
    for (i=0; i<Nx; i++)
    {
        sum1 += vol1[i];
        sum2 += vol2[i];
    }
    end = clock();
    elapsedTime = (double)(end - start) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;

    printf("The enclosed Volume is: %lf\n", (sum2 - sum1));
    printf("The total time taken is: %lf\n", elapsedTime);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried with `gettimeofday()`?

Comment: `clock()` doesn't measure real time on most Unix systems but the combined CPU time of all process threads. There are like hundreds of similar questions here. Use `omp_get_wtime()` instead.

Comment: I have used omp_get_wtime() for the openMP code, can i use it for the simple C code as well? The time given by the OpenMP code is correct. It's the C code time which is faulty.

Comment: _clock() doesn't measure real time on most Unix systems_...  Or any other system (for the same reason given by @HristoIliev).

Comment: @ryyker, `clock()` measures real time on Windows.

Comment: @HristoIliev -  You are kidding, right?  Windows is not real-time, never has been.

Comment: Substitute "real time" with "wall-clock time" in all my previous comments.

Comment: @HristoIliev - from my man page on `clock()`:  _Returns the number of system clock cycles that have occurred since the program started executing._  ***The number of clock ticks can include time used by other processes.***

Comment: @HristoIliev, to be more accurate I think on Windows that `clock()` measures the wall time for compilers that use MSVCRT such as Visual Studio and MinGW. However, since MinGW-w64 does not use MSVCRT I suspect that `clock` acts like `clock` on unix.